# When choosing an SSL certificate, what is the minimum encryption level needed to benefit from Google's HTTPS ranking signal?

Tags: seo, google, https

In August, Google announced HTTPS as a ranking signal. But in order to benefit from this ranking factor, you need to use a 2048-bit encryption. I have only seen websites with 128-bit and 256-bit encryption. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your title and body text are two completely different questions. For the question title, the answer is 'SHA-2', [best explained here](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1). For the body, there is an excellent answer over on the [InfoSec SE site here](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19473). Basically, one is a master key and it is used to generate a smaller session key. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

*2048 bit signatures*

You seem to be mixing up the signed certification to that of the actual encryption rate. Nowadays most good SSL providers will use a NIST recommended 2048 bit signed certification, because SHA2 is becoming the norm and actually recommended encryption rate you should be looking for is 256bit minimal however [SHA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) supports 224, 256, 384 or 512 bits.